# I want to select my created parent element and prints to console

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I want to select this div and prints to console i tried this but not working

```js
let divList = document.createElement('div')
    divList.setAttribute("id","container")
    parentEl.appendChild(divList)
    console.log(document.getElementbyId('container')
```

Comment: what is `parentEl` ? your snippet is incomplete

Comment: this is a parent elemet of a container

Comment: You want to print the PARENT element to console? Id container is the CHILD element. Why dont you Just print parentEl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo it's "getElementById" not "getElementbyId";

```
let divList = document.createElement('div');

divList.setAttribute("id", "container");
parentEl.appendChild(divList);

console.log(document.getElementById('container'));
```